# How to create list with forms?

Tags: python, django

I would create forms with fields.
The number of fields depends on the user. For example, we have a list to do:

To do:

1. ....
2. ....
3. ....

+add more

Detail:
The simple form is:

```
class ListToDoForms(forms.Form):
    do = forms.CharField()
    do1 = forms.CharField()
    do2 = forms.CharField()
    ...
```

The number of fields depends on the number of variables in the example above.
Is it possible to create a form that will be universal for an unknown quantity variable "do"?

Comment: please more clarify your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use django Formsets

```
from django.forms import modelformset_factory

class ListToDoForms(forms.Form):
    do = forms.CharField()

formset_class = modelformset_factory(
        model=Model_name, 
        fields=('do'), 
        extra=0, 
        can_delete=True)
```